# My own VBA codes in a PowerPoint file .pptm suddenly disabled though I put no Security limitation in the settings

Tags: vba, security, powerpoint

My own VBA codes in a PowerPoint file .pptm  suddenly got disabled though I put no Security limitation in the settings. Going through MS help pages nothing working could be found.

The issue could be described as follow:

- I see some codes that I cannot run in the "Macros" window
- Other codes, including those used by the visible ones, are not shown, though I can edit them in the "modules". But when trying to run them by F5 or the Run button, the "Macros" window opens and show only the previous list (that I cannot run either)

I am using "Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit"

What I did so far:

- Set the Security Settings in Developer tab of the PowerPoint app to "Enable all ..."
- Restarted several time my file
- I tried to change the file's security properties in the Windows Explorer, but nothing seems open for modification (though I am Admin on my device); maybe there is a need to set something else before that in the Windows settings or Control Panel, but I ignore.

Any idea how to figure out this?

Comment: Because of a typo in my VBA code, the file I was working on crashed and I could not retrieve anything as PowerPoint would crash each time I tried to open it. So I used LibreOffice to open the file and from there I was able to copy the macros and paste them to a new file (of course, after having replaced "Rem" with "").